# Source of forkjoin() not recognized as function

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-observables, fork-join

I'm using a ForkJoin to wait on 3 objects. Calling their getters inside the fork join seems not to work, giving the error seen below. The same method is called multiple times throughout the project, but does not seem to work in side a ForkJoin. There are no compile errors, the error is given when the code is run. Can anybody explain to me why?

It is my first time using ForkJoin and have been using the RXJS documentation to learn.

MailService / mail.service.ts:

```
import {HttpClient,HttpErrorResponse,HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {forkJoin,Observable,throwError,} from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { Booking } from './booking/booking.model';
import { Camper } from './camper/camper.model';
import { User } from 'src/app/modules/user/user.model';

import { UserDataService } from 'src/app/modules/user/user.data.service';
import { CamperDataService } from 'src/app/modules/camper/camper.data.service';
import { BookingDataService } from 'src/app/booking/booking.data.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MailService {
  public headers = new HttpHeaders({'Authorization': environment.apiKey});

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private _userDataService: UserDataService,
    private _bookingDataService: BookingDataService,
    private _camperDataService: CamperDataService
  ) {}

  sendMailNewBooking(booking: Booking) {
    console.log('start mail service');
    var body;

    forkJoin({
      camper: this._camperDataService.getCamper$(booking.camperId),
      user: this._userDataService.getUser$(booking.travellerId),
      auth: this._userDataService.getAuthZeroData$(booking.travellerId),
    }).subscribe({
      next: ({ camper, user, auth }) => {
        body = {
          booking: booking,
          camper: camper,
          user: user,
          email: auth.email,
        };
      },
      error: (err) => console.error(err),
    });

    console.log('body =>');
    console.log(body);

    var call = this.http
      .post(`${environment.apiUrl}/mail/newbooking/`, body, {
        headers: this.headers,
      })
      .pipe(tap(console.log), catchError(this.handleError));
    return call;
  }
}
```

UserDataService / user.data.service:

```
import {HttpClient,HttpErrorResponse,HttpHeaders,HttpParams} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { User } from './user.model';
import { catchError, map, switchMap, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { Auth0Management } from 'src/app/auth0-management.model';
import { MailService } from 'src/app/modules/mail.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class UserDataService {
  private _reloadUsers$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);
  public headers = new HttpHeaders({'Authorization': environment.apiKey});
  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient,private _mailService: MailService ) {}

  getUser$(this: UserDataService, id: string): Observable<User> {
    console.log("User id? -> " + id);
    
    return this.http
      .get(`${environment.apiUrl}/users/${id}`, {headers: this.headers})
      .pipe(tap(console.log), catchError(this.handleError), map(User.fromJSON));
  }
}
```

The mail service method is called as such:

```
this._bookingDataService.addNewBooking(createdBooking)
        .subscribe((bkn: Booking) => {
            console.log('sending mail new booking');
            this._mailService.sendMailNewBooking(bkn);
        }
```

It is on the page where the booking gets made.

Output:

```
main.js:1 start mail service
main.js:1 ERROR TypeError: this._userDataService.getUser$ is not a function
    at n.sendMailNewBooking (main.js:1:156389)
    at Object.next (main.js:1:913301)
    at Me.next (main.js:1:1219971)
    at Ee._next (main.js:1:1219651)
    at Ee.next (main.js:1:1219345)
    at se._next (main.js:1:1219651)
    at se.next (main.js:1:1219345)
    at o.subscribe.h (main.js:1:56772)
    at se._next (main.js:1:1226106)
    at se.next (main.js:1:1219345)
```

Comment: Please show your full code : the constructor of your component, as well as the decorator of your service.

Comment: 1.  It's strange syntax that you're declaring the method `getUser$` that way.  I rarely see that, but *it* should be valid.
2.  That means there is something going on in MailService that we can't see.  Like how that method is being called.  So we need to see more of the MailService.

Comment: I updated my question. I also changed the ```getuser$``` still have the same problem. Sorry if i gave too much, it is my first question.

Comment: I couldn't find anything wrong, but looks like you have circular dependencies between `MailService` and `UserDataScervice`, normally this will report an error when run it. Read more here https://angular.io/errors/NG0200, if it really exists in your code, try to remove it and run again, it may help.